# Probability of obtain a base of a Boolean Space

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Using the technical lemma that: for a vector space $V$, $S$ a linear independant subset of $V$ and $v\in V$. Then $S\cup\{v\}$ is linear independant if and only if $v\notin \langle S\rangle$.

We can calculate the number of basis of $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ with $p$ prime.

Beginning with $S=\emptyset$, we can choose any vector different from zero. So $S_1=\{v_1\}$ is linear independant. This vector we have $p^n-1$ choices. Now, we have to choose a vector $v_2$ from $\mathbb{Z}_p^n\setminus\langle v_1\rangle$. For this, we have $p^n-p$. Continue with this process, the las vector $v_n$ has $p^n-p^{n-1}$ choices.

Then the number of basis are $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} p^n-p^i$.

So if we take $n$ random vector the probability of obtain a basis is $\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} p^n-p^i}{(p^n)^n}=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (1-\frac{p^i}{p^n})$.

If we fix $p=2$, we extract vectors from $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ with replacement. We define $X$ as the random varible of the first time that the extracted vectors generate $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$, or equivalently that the extracted vectors have a subset that is a basis.

Which is the density function of $X$?